# Fourier series of smooth functions in infinitely many variables

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $J$ be a set (usually countable). Let $t_j$, $j\in J$, be variables in ${\mathbb R}/2\pi i{\mathbb Z}.$ Put $u_j=\exp(it_j),$ $j\in J.$ Introduce the following semi-norms on the space of Fourier polynomials ${\mathbb C}[u_j^{\pm 1}|j\in J]:$ for $N\geq 0,$ put
$$||f||_N=\max_{t\in (S^1)^J} \sum _{|\alpha|=N} |\partial ^{[\alpha ]} f(t)|$$
where the sum is taken over multi-indices $\alpha=(\alpha_j|j\in J)$; $\alpha_j\geq 0;$ $|\alpha|=\sum_{j\in J}\alpha_j;$ and $\partial ^{[\alpha ]}=\prod_{j\in J} \frac{1}{\alpha_j !}(\frac{\partial}{\partial t_j})^{\alpha_j}$.

Let $C^\infty ((S^1)^J)$  be the completion of ${\mathbb C}[u_j^{\pm 1}|j\in J]$ in the topology defined by these semi-norms.

**Question**. How to describe $C^\infty((S^1)^J)$ in terms of the Fourier coefficients $a_n$?

Comment: Are you **sure** you *want* to consider these metrics?  The usefulness of Cᵏ lies in a bound for k⸣th derivatives leading to a **bound on variation** of k-1⸣st derivatives.  However (if I did not miss something) you essentially work in (a class of) metrics on a torus for which the diameter of the torus is infinite.  Would not it be better to “allow more metrics on the torus” (leading to more metrics on C∞) so that the estimate mentioned above works?

Comment: Just an example: when I have been investigating the Jacobian of a curve of genus ∞, I was using the topology which is essentially equivalent to a direct product topology.  This topology is “infinitely coarser” than the topology on the torus you (apparently) want to consider…  (It is in my preprint of ∼’95.)

Comment: Preprint of '97?

Comment: Yes, coarser topology is good, if one can find it in such a way that the automorphisms and differential-difference operators that I need extend to the completion...

Comment: (Yes, it is ’97!)  In the simplest setup, one takes a product of several circles of radii Rᵢ.  If Rᵢ → 0, then the topology is the topology of the direct product.  If (Rᵢ)∈ℓ₂, then an estimate of k⸣th derivatives gives a estimate for a variation of k-1⸣st derivative (as above).  I would think that if (Rᵢ)∈ℓ₁, then most of the “expected” properties would hold.  Still, I would try to start with considering the case when (Rᵢ) are rapidly decreasing.  (Should not be hard to cover this case…)

Comment: (I put my answer here, since I think you misplaced your question, below.) — With “Example: tₙ↦tₙ+t₁” (again, I corrected what I think is a misprint): anything which touches only a finite number of factors S¹ is going to be continuous “no matter what is the setup”.  Moreover, with R₁=1 above, this would probably become tₙ↦tₙ+Rₙt₁, and Rₙ is going to be very small; so infinitely many of such transformations can be “combined” without causing too much harm…

Answer (score 0):

This is an off-the-cuff answer so really a comment but too long for that.  If you fix the dimension at $p$ then the space you get is $C^\infty(E_p)$, where $E_p$ is $n$–dimensional euclidean space. As $p$ increases, you get a natural projective spectrum of (nuclear Fréchet) spaces.  I assume the space that you want is its projective limit—also an $(FN)$-space in the countable case.  The required condition on the coefficients is that for each $p$ the restriction of the multi-sequence $(\alpha_j)$ to the first $p$ coordinates is rapidly decreasing in the sense of L. Schwartz.

Comment: @Ilya Zakharevich projective limits do not work for me, if I am not mistaken. What I need is that certain automorphisms of the infinite dimensional torus extend to the completion. Example: $t_n\mapsto t_{n+1}-t_1.$ Actually I need also some differential-difference operators, i.e. (infinite) sums of such automorphisms composed with partial derivatives, to extend to the completion.